# How to pass arguments to an isolated scope when using & in custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a function in my controller scope

```
$scope.read = function(a, b, c){};
```

I've binded it to my custom directive

```
<dir read="read(a, b, c)"></dir>
```

And my custom directive

```
angular.module('app').directive('dir', function() {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    read: '&'
  },
  link: function() {
    read(a, b, c); 
  }
});
```

When I debuged it, all three arguments are `undefined`. 
How can I make it work?

Comment: if you want to pass function pass it as reference using `=` and just the function name as value

Comment: Only function is bound through your scope declaration in directive, in your link function invoke read(1,2,3) because a, b, c are not available in your directive scope, you may need to bind each argument explicitly using  `=`

Comment: Nikos Paraskevopoulos did solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to call the function from the directive is:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.read({a: your_a_argument, b: your_b_argument, c: your_c_argument});
}
```